# Why is sheets name VBA property no longer working?

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code to try to loop through each sheet and apply some basic formatting and comments to trim down my work on projects.  This was working fine all week and I'm not sure what changed to make it stop working today.  I believe the only changes I made were below this code and it was to add comments and indentations.  Neither sheets.name or worksheets.name is working anymore for this specific line of code.  What's odd is that if I run sheets.activate or msgbox(sheets().name), that works, but the "sheets(x).name like" line throws the error "Object doesn't support this property or method".

```
Dim x As Integer
x = Sheets.Count
    Do While x > 0
        MsgBox (Sheets(x).Name)
        If Sheets(x).Name Like "*Juniper application*" Then
            Sheets(x).Activate
            y = Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
            Do While y > 1
                If Cells(y, 2).Value Like "*Using a Check Point service instead*" Then
                    Cells(y, 3).Value = "Yes"
                    Cells(y, 4).Value = "Application equivalent conversion performed"
                  Else
                    Cells(y, 3).Value = "No"
                End If
                y = y - 1
            Loop
        End If
'...Other If then statements
    x = x-1
Loop
```

Comment: Qualify the sheets with workbook?

Comment: It would be better to loop over the `Worksheets`, not `Sheets`, with a `For Each` loop: `Dim ws As Worksheet`, `For Each ws in ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets`.

Comment: @BigBen, thanks.  I don't know why the code stopped working, but your suggestion did fix the issue.  I need to start thinking of for loops instead of do loops.